# Low memory killer because of ffmpeg in Android

Tags: android, memory-management, ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming

I'm running an application in Android embedded card. The application is implemented in C. It runs an ffmpeg process using `system()` API which streams transport stream data over IP. When I started the application, approximately 2 hours later, low memory killer daemon is killing the background processes slowly. After some time it's killing the application also. And the GUI screen is hanged completely.
ffmpeg command:
`ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -re -i "udp://192.168.47.1:8080?buffer_size=10000000&fifo_size=100000000&overrun_nonfatal=1" -map 0:p:1 -f mpegts udp://192.168.47.172:9090?pkt_size=1316`

low memory killer log:

```
[ 7975.838158@2] lowmemorykiller: Killing 'droid.deskclock' (4779), adj 906,
[ 7975.838158@2]    to free 18940kB on behalf of 'kswapd0' (1978) because
[ 7975.838158@2]    cache 109744kB is below limit 114688kB for oom_score_adj 529
[ 7975.838158@2]    Free memory is 9276kB above reserved. nonmove free (32936kB),(63700kB)
[ 7976.045769@2] lowmemorykiller: Killing 'd.process.media' (4902), adj 906,
[ 7976.045769@2]    to free 23028kB on behalf of 'kswapd0' (1978) because
[ 7976.045769@2]    cache 112320kB is below limit 114688kB for oom_score_adj 529
[ 7976.045769@2]    Free memory is 5440kB above reserved. nonmove free (31148kB),(66164kB)
```

Query:

- Does ffmpeg consume more CPU & memory over the course of time, which in turn causing low memory killer?

Comment: If you don't need to re-encode add the `-c copy` output option. It will consume less CPU and memory.

Comment: thank you llogan. I've updated the ffmpeg command as "ffmpeg -loglevel warning -re -i udp://192.168.47.1:8080?buffer_size=5000000&fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1\" -map 0:p:1 -c copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.47.172:9090?pkt_size=1316".  With the updated command CPU utilization is improved significantly. But the memory leakage is still there but it is at a slower pace as fifo_size is reduced. Can the command be optimized further to avoid slow memory leakage.

Comment: You shouldn't need `-re` for live UDP input. From [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options): *`-re` Should not be used with actual grab devices or live input streams (where it can cause packet loss).*. Only suggestion I have is to try the most recent ffmpeg. I have no idea what you're using.

Comment: I'm using ffmpeg 4.2.1 static binary in embedded system. I'll try with -re option.

Comment: 4.2.1 is old. Try a build from the git master branch.